# Sylius + Vagrant + Behat not working

Tags: symfony, testing, vagrant, behat, sylius

we are trying to run Behat tests inside vagrant machine, but we keep always getting problems.

This is Vagrant machine we are using https://github.com/vranac/vagrant-sylius-setup

So first issue was with cookies, we resolved that but now every scenario that is @javascript is failing

Here is example [image]

In screenshot which we got after error is says that route is missing?

Any Idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you using open() method inside the failing step? It seems its checking if is on a certain page by URL but finds different page.

Comment: I am facing the very same problem. I did not realize this was in any way related to vagrant VM (but yes, my issue is in the VM too). Have you had any luck in resolving this? If so, could you share the answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced and managed to resolve this particular issue.

The key issue was the fact that ChromeWebdriver version (2.29) was either incompatible with Google Chrome version (59.0) or it had a bug in regards to setting cookies (Changelog does mention some work on cookies).

A working combination for me currently is ChromeDriver 2.30 + Google Chrome 59.0 - check those versions.

Another thing I had to change was the session handler to use proper sessions instead of mocksess(ions). In `app/config/config_test.yml` I've change the `framework` > `session` section like this:

```
framework:
    test: ~
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '/tmp/php-sessions'
```

And yet another thing to check is if the sessions are created/read/written without any permission issues. I did face an issue at one point where I was running behat with `vagrant` user so it created the session file with this user as owner, but when it went through Selenium/Chrome back to the webserver then it tried to access it with `www-data` user and failed due to permission restrictions. As a workaround, I am now running behat under `www-data` user as well: `sudo -E -u www-data bin/behat ...`. Similar issues may happen for caches too.

It seems that for Vagrant specifically Sylius forces cache/log directories to be placed in `/dev/shm/sylius`, which in case of shared dir (between host and guest) is a performance boost, but also implies strict permission checks (See https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/79a5285/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Application/Kernel.php#L162-L164 )